# How to add footnote in JSON

Tags: json, footnotes

### Goal

I want to store a document content as JSON and have not found a good example how to handle footnotes.

---

### Possible solution

I have provided how a rendered document (Word/PDF) might look like and made a JSON from the best of my knowledge.

#### Rendered document

[image]

#### JSON

```
{
  "content": "This is some text with a reference^1 to something",
  "footnotes":
  [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "footnote": "That special something"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "footnote": "Some other thing"
    },
  ]
}
```

If I do it this way I have to search for `^[footnote id]` when I merge/render a document and display it correctly.

---

### Question

Is this the way to do it or is there a better maybe standardized way to solve this?

Comment: So what about the `^1`, is that the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way could be like this:

```
{
  "content": "This is some text with a reference^1 to something",
  "footnotes": {
      "1": "That special something"
      "2": "Some other thing"
  }
}
```

If you store it in an Object instead of an Array, it will be easier to find / access.

Comment: I like your tip for using "1" as attribute key.